# Java - Print First and Last date for each month within specified given month-year range

Tags: java, date, calendar

How can I print all months first and the last date which falls within the given specified Month-Year range?
So far I have the code which prints for 1 complete year example, if in the input year 2019 is provided then the first and the last date of all 12 months is printed. But what I want is it should print values within the specified Month-Year range.

Example,

```
String input_StartMonthYear = "1-2019";
String input_EndMonthYear = "6-2020";


Expected Output:

firstDay-> 2019-1-1
lastDay-> 2019-1-31

firstDay-> 2019-2-1
lastDay-> 2019-2-28

---
---

firstDay-> 2020-6-1
lastDay-> 2020-6-30
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class GetDate_Firt_Last {

    static String input_Year = "2019";
    static String completeinput;
    static int totalmonths[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};



    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
    {

        int m;
        for (m = 1;m <= totalmonths.length;m++)
        {
            completeinput = m + "-" + input_Year;


            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy");
            Date date = sdf.parse(completeinput);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);



            getFirstDayOfTheMonth(cal);
            getLastDayOfTheMonth(cal);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }


    public static String getFirstDayOfTheMonth(Calendar cal) throws Exception {
        String firstDay;

        try {

            int firstDate = cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE);

            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1;
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            firstDay = year + "-" + month + "-" + firstDate;
            System.out.println("firstDay-> " +firstDay);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Exception in getFirstDayOfTheMonth." + e.getMessage());
        }
        return firstDay;
    }





    public static String getLastDayOfTheMonth(Calendar cal) throws Exception {
        String lastDay;
        try {

            int lastDate = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            lastDay = year + "-" + month + "-" + lastDate;
            System.out.println("lastDay-> "+ lastDay);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Exception in getLastDateOfTheMonth." + e.getMessage());
        }
        return lastDay;
    }


}
```

Actual Output:

```
firstDay-> 2019-1-1
lastDay-> 2019-1-31

firstDay-> 2019-2-1
lastDay-> 2019-2-28

---
---

firstDay-> 2019-12-1
lastDay-> 2019-12-31
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to achieve and you are always going to December because your `for loop` is set to the always go to December as `totalMonths.length` is equal to 12. I would suggest maybe switching to LocalDates as they have some fancy functions that make life easier.

Comment: @TOTOROCATBUS Thanks, I had added totalMonths.length when I needed data for 1 year only. But now my question is I want to print the first and the last date for a specific date range so not sure how I can iterate the loop till specific month-year range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use java 8 or higher something like this could be a first approach

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

public class GetDate_Firt_Last {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input_StartMonthYear = "1-2019";
        String input_EndMonthYear = "6-2020";
        
        DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-yyyy");
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("1-" +input_StartMonthYear, df);
        LocalDate end   = LocalDate.parse("1-" + input_EndMonthYear, df);
        for(LocalDate d = start; d.isBefore(end.plusMonths(1)); d = d.plusMonths(1)){
            System.out.println("firstDay -> " + d.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfMonth()));
            System.out.println("lastDay -> " + d.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int monthsBetween = Months.monthsBetween(start, end).getMonths();` can be used to get the number of months to make the for loop more adjustable then you can just have a LocalDate holding the start LocalDate that you just add the loop value onto

Answer (score 1):

Eritrean’s answer is fine. In case you fancy a stream solution, here’s one:

```
    DateTimeFormatter monthYearFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-u");
    Period step = Period.ofMonths(1);
    
    String inputStartMonthYear = "1-2019";
    String inputEndMonthYear = "6-2020";

    LocalDate startDateInclusive
            = YearMonth.parse(inputStartMonthYear, monthYearFormatter).atDay(1);
    LocalDate endDateExclusive = YearMonth
            .parse(inputEndMonthYear, monthYearFormatter)
            .plusMonths(1)
            .atDay(1);
    
    startDateInclusive.datesUntil(endDateExclusive, step)
            .forEach(d1 -> {
                System.out.println("firstDay-> " + d1);
                LocalDate endOfMonth = d1.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
                System.out.println("lastDay-> " + endOfMonth);
            });
```

The output is longish, so I am giving you just the first and the last lines:

> ```
> firstDay-> 2019-01-01
> lastDay-> 2019-01-31
> firstDay-> 2019-02-01
> lastDay-> 2019-02-28
> firstDay-> 2019-03-01
> lastDay-> 2019-03-31
> firstDay-> 2019-04-01
> lastDay-> 2019-04-30
> (... cut ...)
> firstDay-> 2020-05-01
> lastDay-> 2020-05-31
> firstDay-> 2020-06-01
> lastDay-> 2020-06-30
> ```